# Hide dynamic-rows column via js

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom-options, uicomponent, dynamic-rows

I am looking for a way to hide several dynamic rows columns (the same way setVisibilityColumn() method in dynamic-rows.js does) on checkbox value being changed. Checkbox is located on adminside custom options table, in option row like here: [image: Custom Options]
The columns I want to hide are both in option and  value rows ("TO HIDE #")
Currently I have made a component for checkbox and listen to onChecked event but I don't know how exactly should I access the dynamic rows to hide those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ui component for each depended field and:

- link component's **visible** property with the checkbox's **checked** property
- update component's visibility on initialization

UI Component for the **TO HIDE #1** and **TO HIDE #2** fields will be:

```
define([
  'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
], function (Abstract) {

  return Abstract.extend({
    defaults: {
      imports: {
        visible: '${ $.parentName }.checkbox:checked',
      }
    },

    initialize: function () {
      this._super();
      this.visible(this.visible());
    }
  });
});
```

UI Component for the **TO HIDE #3** and **TO HIDE #4** fields will be:

```
define([
  'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
], function (Element) {
  'use strict';

  return Element.extend({

    defaults: {
      imports: {
        visible: '${ $.parentName.replace(/\\.values\\.[\\d]+/, \'\') }.container_common.checkbox:checked',
      }
    },

    initialize: function () {
      this._super();
      this.visible(this.visible());
    }

  });
});
```

**Related links:**

1. [UI Components’ properties used for linking](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui_components_js.html#comp_link)
2. [Template Literals in UI Components](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_template_literals.html)